# The function addpath() won't give access to files in subfolder

Tags: path, subdirectory

I have lots of data files in a subfolder. But nothing happens when I try to access them by using addpath(). It seems like the path search is stuck to the folder of which the script is run from.

The script is saved in `Y:\97 Master\RiometerData\ASCII`

The datafiles I want to access are stored in 
`Y:\97 Master\RiometerData\ASCII\S05\2011`

I have multiple subfolders of S01-S05, each containing several years of data.

I have tried both `addpath('Y:\97 Master\RiometerData\ASCII\S05\2011')` and `addpath('S05\2011')`. It works perfectly if I move the file to my ASCII-folder, but not when it's stored in a subfolder.

```
addpath('Y:\97 Master\RiometerData\ASCII\S05\2011')
fileName = 'testFile.txt';
if isfile(fileName)
    data = load(fileName);
else
    fprintf('File %s does> not exist.\n', fileName)
end
```

The code runs without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! 
isfile() requires full the path. Not enough (necessary) with addpath(). Moved testfile to `Y:\97 Master\RiometerData\ASCII\subFolder1\SubFolder2` for the sake of example. This is not the easiest way for this example, but if there are many files I need to being able to change paths and filenames. For single files it would be enough to write:

```
if isfile('Y:\97 Master\RiometerData\ASCII\subFolder1\SubFolder2\testFile.txt')
   %data = load(file)
```

.

```
currPath = pwd;

subFolderPath = 'subFolder1\SubFolder2';
filePath = sprintf('%s%c%s%c',currPath,'\',subFolderPath,'\');
fileName = 'testFile.txt'

file = sprintf('%s%s',filePath,fileName)

if isfile(file)
    data = load(file)
else
    fprintf('File does not exist.\n')
end
```